# jquery created select, and triggering on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I cannot seem to get this to work.  I am using jquery to create an html select, and I want some code to execute when its value changes.

code follows:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

   var firstweddingturn = '400';

   $('#weddingturn').change(function() {

      alert ("Wedding select change triggered!");

      //var wedturn = $('#weddingturnselectid').val();
      //$('#div3').append('<br>Wedding turn selected, ' + wedturn + '</br>')

    });


    $(document).ready(function() {

      var html = [];
      html[html.length] = '<select name="weddingturn" id="weddingturn">';
      var a = firstweddingturn;
      var b = Number(firstweddingturn) + 16;
      while (a < b) {
        // do some code
        html[html.length] = '<option name="asdf" value = "1">' + a + '</option>';
        a++;
      }  // end while
      html[html.length] = '</select>';
      $('#div1').append(html.join('')); 

    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this case, the select is being created later, through the execution of other jquery code.  My example here was fudged for simplicity.

Comment: But you *know* when you're creating it, don't you?  The element is not being added as a mysterious consequence of some library.  Just bind the event handler then.  `.live` and `.delegate` are specialty function that are used only in very peculiar circumstances.  In four years of writing jQuery, I've never need them.

Comment: Also, `html[html.length]=x` is perfectly legal Javascript but `html.push(x)` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (or [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) since you are adding the select dynamically. When you attach an onChange handler with `.change()` it is only attached to **existing** matching elements, not elements which are added later on. To attach an event to all matching elements including those added to the page later, you use the `.delegate()` function, like this:

```
$('body').delegate('#weddingturn','change', function(){
  alert('Wedding select changed to ' + $(this).find('option:selected').val() );
});
```

However, as some people point out, you can merely attach the event handler immediately after adding the `<select>` to the DOM. That way, you can still use `.change()` and your code should run faster.

Comment: You do *not* "need" to use bind!

Comment: Technically you're correct - attaching the event handler after adding the `select` would work too.

However, I figured if he wasn't going to alter the `select` later on, he would have just hardcoded the HTML rather than generating it dynamically. Using `.live()` gives him that option.

Comment: He should use Delegates as live isn't recommended

Answer (score 1):

Include this:

```
 $('#weddingturn').live('change', function() {

        alert ("Wedding select change triggered!");

        //var wedturn = $('#weddingturnselectid').val();

        //$('#div3').append('<br>Wedding turn selected, ' + wedturn + '</br>')

    });
```

in your `$(document).ready`

And change it to use `live`

Answer (score 1):

When the `.change()` event is bound, the element does not exist yet. You have 2 choices:

1. Bind the event after you create the element (**the simplest and recommended option**)
2. Use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (or [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) to tell jQuery to bind the event to any element matching the selector whenever it is added to the DOM. If you choose this option, `delegate()` is the preferred method if you are using a recent version of jQuery `> 1.4.2` since it is more performant than `live()`.

Comment: Huh?  How would `.delegate` be more "performant" than just moving the damn code?

Comment: @Malvolio ah, that part was supposed to be part in the second option. Correction incoming

Comment: I get it.  Yes, `.delegate` is better than `.live` but just moving the code to the right place is better still.

Answer (score 0):

your are dynamically adding the `select` to the DOM, at the time of declaration of your event handler the `select` doest not exists so the event handler doesn't get binded to the element  use `.live` to attach the event handler to dynamically added element

```
$('#weddingturn').live('change',function() {

        alert ("Wedding select change triggered!");

        //var wedturn = $('#weddingturnselectid').val();

        //$('#div3').append('<br>Wedding turn selected, ' + wedturn + '</br>')

    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MecUs/5/)

[`jquery live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bind using `live`, since it is loaded post-DOM load:

```
$("#weddingturn").live("change", function() {

});
```

Also, I would place this within scope of `$(document).ready`, preferably after the code which loads it (just for the sake of logical linearity.)

Answer (score 0):

You're hooking up the event handler BEFORE you've created the element.

(you can use .live() or you can just swap the order of operations)

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the `change` function on a select that does not yet exist.  Move that `.change` call to after the `.append`