# how to use bind() instead of live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how to use bind in jquery.

I have a page which, after a button press, does the following code:

```
var html = [];
html.push('<select name="weddingturn" id="weddingturn">');
var a = firstweddingturn;
var b = Number(firstweddingturn) + 16;
while (a < b) {
  // do some code
  html.push('<option name="asdf">' + a + '</option>');
  a++;
 }  // end while
html.push('</select>');
$('#div1').append(html.join(''));
```

I also want to catch any changes to that select, once it is set up.

```
var firstweddingturn = '400';

$('#weddingturn').live('change',function() {

  alert ("Wedding select change triggered!");

  //var wedturn = $('#weddingturnselectid').val();
  //$('#div3').append('<br>Wedding turn selected, ' + wedturn + '</br>')

});
```

I would greatly appreciate someone showing and explaining how to use bind() in this instead of live().

For context sake, please see here:  [jquery created select, and triggering on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126429/jquery-created-select-and-triggering-on-change)

Comment: Here's a good article I came across on bind, live, and delegate http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Comment: `live` is `bind` with the added benefit of binding to *future* elements that match the *selector* that live was bound to. Also, remember that an id **must** be unique to the page; `$("#id")` will only return one matching element (as will `document.getElementById("id")`).

Answer (score 2):

Just swap:

```
$('#weddingturn').live('change',function() {
```

to:

```
$('#weddingturn').bind('change',function() {
```

`.live` should've solved your problem - so what is the exact reason or problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#weddingturn').live('change',function(){});
```

This site explains the difference very well: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Answer (score 2):

There is also a shorthand for bind() for certain events. You can make your code shorter by doing:

```
$('#weddingturn').change(function() {
```

Keep in mind though that `bind()` and `live()` do fundamentally different things. `live()` affects everything with the given selectors, while `bind()` will only bind events to elements that are already on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on when you are calling live or bind - after or before those html element available. If you are calling bind after those html element is available on that page, it should be OK to swap. Otherwise, I think bind would not work.